# append results of third column if the values of other two columns for n rows are same in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

My sql query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.user_login, a.user_email, c.domain
FROM wp_users a
JOIN wp_usermeta b ON a.id = b.user_id
JOIN wp_blogs c ON b.meta_value = c.site_id
WHERE user_login != SUBSTRING_INDEX( user_email,  '@', 1 ) 
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

the results are like below

```
user_login      user_email           domain
ff              ff@asd.com           a.b.c
ff              ff@asd.com           f.g.h
aa              aa@asd.com           a.b.c
aa              aa@asd.com           b.n.m
```

I need the results to be like

```
 user_login      user_email           domain
 ff              ff@asd.com           a.b.c,f.g.h
 aa              aa@asd.com           a.b.c,b.n.m
```

I am new to sql, I could not determine what concept I mean to get result in this way.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.user_login, a.user_email, GROUP_CONCAT(c.domain)
FROM wp_users a
JOIN wp_usermeta b ON a.id = b.user_id
JOIN wp_blogs c ON b.meta_value = c.site_id
WHERE user_login != SUBSTRING_INDEX( user_email,  '@', 1 ) 
GROUP BY user_login  
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

Comment: @Naren yes I thought that's what you want according to the results above

Comment: did you add group by user_login ?